# Genymotion / Android: Keyboard Input and Big Icons

Tags: android, genymotion

I am using `androVM_vbox86tp_4.1.1_r6.1-20130222-gapps-houdini-flash` with `VirtualBox-4.2.12` and `Genymotion v1.0` in Windows 7 x64.

It is a fast VM emulator for android (Fast Startup, Fast APK Upload and Fast Debugging). But it has some problems.

One of the problems is apps icons. As you can see they are big and not well-formed:

[image]

Another one is the keyboard input that is not in English:
( Although the **language & input** setting is in **English (US)** )

[image]

Is there any workaround for these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon size is probably due to a strange resolution you configure.  The AOSP launcher does not support well not standard screen formats.

Also, it seems that you run an AndroVM virtual machine.
Try to use instead, the default templates offered by the player (the application that comes with Genymotion). Update it (because since the last week the version is 1.1. And download the templates you want to use. It should work.

About the keyboard, I think it has been solved on 1.1. If not send a message though the support page : https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/#